# Connecting Excel VBA to sql server using ODBC Connections and Objects

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, odbc

I am new to coding, i am recently working on a Stock Control Program using Excel and VBA, at first i can run and get results on my designer, but the more buttons and labels that i add on it becomes a problem to run!

- Error 1
  I Keep getting an automation error.
- I understood that the error was related to database connection, so i proceeded to connecting to the database. using the code bellow:

  ```
  Sub DbConnection()
  Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
  Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

  Dim strConn As String
  strConn = "Driver={SQL Server}; Server=servername; Database=Dbname; VID=username; PWD=password"

  cn.Open strConn
  cn.Close
  Set cn = Nothing
  MsgBox "Connected"
  End Sub
  ```
- I used the Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 6.1 library.
  but i realized that it is not working and was recommended to use ODBC Connection, and now i am stuck, Can anyone help me on this?
- How do i use this connection for my ODBC Connection?
- Anything I am doing Wrong? Which Reference Object do i have to use?
  PS: I am using Ms Excel 2016 and SSMS 2017. Thanks

Comment: `Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 6.1` is fine to use for early binding ADODB objects. If this connection was working before - it is not likely causing the issue. You said you started getting errors when you added more controls. What code is running behind these "problem" controls?

Comment: "You said you started getting errors when you added more controls. What code is running behind these "problem" controls?"  Well, that is the problem, I have not yet used any code on! this is all happening with the designer userform!